# Use "set timing on" in Unix shell script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am using the below syntax in a shell script to execute few procedures in parallel:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo"exec procedure_1"|sqlplus USR/PASS@TNS & >> $LogFile
echo"exec procedure_2"|sqlplus USR/PASS@TNS & >> $LogFile
```

I need the execution timing in the log file but SET TIMING ON is not working if used as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo"SET TIMING ON exec procedure_1"|sqlplus USR/PASS@TNS & >> $LogFile
echo"SET TIMING ON exec procedure_2"|sqlplus USR/PASS@TNS & >> $LogFile
```

What am I doing wrong and how would I go about this?

Comment: Hi, when posting a question "not working" is not a useful error description. Can you please explain _exactly_ what's happening and post any error messages you're receiving.

Comment: Most likely, you need a semicolon or newline after SET TIMING ON.  If you were typing at the `sqlplus` prompt, what would you type?  You probably need to emulate that with your `echo` commands.

Comment: -bash-3.2$ echo "set timing on; exec MOZAIC_STG_CUSTOMER_UPDATE;"|sqlplus MIG/MIG@MIGPROD

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Sep 2 09:10:31 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SP2-0158: unknown SET option ";"